# CSS3 Hide/Show Filter button using Child Selectors?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a button to hide and show content using CSS3 child selectors, but the trick only works with minimal markup.

Soon as I add multiple div's inside the section(where the content is placed) The Child Selectors don't hide the content anymore rendering the hide/show button useless.

Any help or a better understanding to what's going on will be greatly appreciated it. Thanks for the help.

Here's the problematic markup:

**CSS:**

```
.please > section:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 62.5%;
}

.please > section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.please {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .25rem;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"] .spanz:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #nomore {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] .spanz:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] .spanz:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="please">

<div id="filter container">

 <input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
 <label for="read_more" onclick=""><span class="spanz">Show Filter</span><span class="spanz">Hide Filter</span></label>     
  <br /><br />

</div>  

<section id="nomore">
<div>
<ul>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<ul>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
</ul>
</div>


<div>
<ul>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
<li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
</ul>
</div>

</section>

</div>
```

And here's the simple markup that works but is not quite what I need.

**CSS:**

```
 .please > section:first-of-type {
    float: right;
    width: 62.5%;
}

.please > section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.please {
    -webkit-transition: .125s linear;
    -moz-transition: .125s linear;
    -ms-transition: .125s linear;
    -o-transition: .125s linear;
    transition: .125s linear;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;

    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: .25rem;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), inset -1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

[for="read_more"]:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
}

[for="read_more"] .spanz:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #nomore {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] .spanz:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for="read_more"] .spanz:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="please">


 <input type="checkbox" id="read_more" role="button">
 <label for="read_more" onclick=""><span class="spanz">Show Filter</span><span class="spanz">Hide Filter</span></label>     
  <br /><br />

<section id="nomore">
    <ul>
    <li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
     <li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
      <li>Owls hunt mostly small mammals</li>
    </ul>

</section>

</div>
```

Comment: can you create a working fiddle please?

Comment: It's not the extra divs in #nomore that are causing the problem...it's the #filter container div.
http://jsfiddle.net/P78hq/1/

Comment: The filter container is needed in order to add a border style and possible background color to separate it from the section. So leaving out the filter container div is not an option.

Comment: I don't know how to fit it and keep the checkbox seperate from the section, but this is your problem: `#read_more[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #nomore {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}`
Sorry, I know that's not much help.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create some input and label for each of the sections to be able to hide/show parts.

I write a sample code for this goal, you can see it

```
<div>
<article>
    <input type="checkbox" id="read_more_1" role="button">
    <label for="read_more_1" class ="button" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide This Shit!</span></label>        
    <section>
        <p>trim content</p>
    </section>    
    <section>
        <p>full content</p>
    </section>
</article>

<article>
    <input type="checkbox" id="read_more_2" role="button">
    <label for="read_more_2" class ="button" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide This Shit!</span></label>        
    <section>
        <p>trim content</p>
    </section>    
    <section>
        <p>full content</p>
    </section>
</article>

<article>
    <input type="checkbox" id="read_more_3" role="button">
    <label for="read_more_3" class ="button" onclick=""><span>Read More</span><span>Hide This Shit!</span></label>        
    <section>
        <p>trim content</p>
    </section>    
    <section>
        <p>full content</p>
    </section>
</article>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
article {
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    position: relative;
    *zoom: 1;
}

article:before, article:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

article:after { clear: both }

article section:first-of-type {
}

article section:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}  


input[type=checkbox] {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    width: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
}

[for^="read_more"] {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -3rem;
}

[for^="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;  
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ section:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for^="read_more"] span:first-of-type {
    display: none;
    visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ [for^="read_more"] span:last-of-type {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

you can run it in (http://jsfiddle.net/shahabal/zrzjd3t1/) link